# map field value and preserve nulls

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to map values (non null) that match a specific value to a bool if they match a specific value, but preserve NULL.

(this is microsoft sql server)

This works but is very ugly...

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN FooId IS NULL
    THEN NULL
    ELSE CASE WHEN FooId = 16 
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
        END 
    END AS FooMapping 
FROM Foo
```

surely there is a better way of doing this?

Comment: No need for nested case expressions. CASE WHEN FooId IS NULL
    THEN NULL
    WHEN FooId = 16 
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
        END AS FooMapping

Comment: `select case when coalesce(FooId, '') = '' then null 
 when coalesce(FooId, 16) = 16 then 1
 else 0 end`

Answer (score 1):

No need for a nested expression:

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN foodid is NULL THEN NULL
         WHEN foodid = 16 THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END As FooMapping
FROM  foo
```

Comment: lovely...better than mine....but still quite clunky....I'll take it for the moment :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think it should look like this (tested at Oracle DB):

```
select decode(FooId,null,null,16,1,0) AS FooMapping
from Foo
```

What it basicly does:

when FooId is null then null

when FooId=16 then 1

default = 0

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: sorry mssql...I'll look up if there is an equivalent though

Answer (score 0):

You can also phrase this as:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN FooId = 16 THEN 1
             WHEN FooId IS NOT NULL THEN 0
        END) AS FooMapping 
FROM Foo
```

The default for a `CASE` expression with no `ELSE` is `NULL`, so if you arrange the logic like this, you can dispense with any `ELSE`.

Comment: ah ha....that looks better...the piece that upset me, was the mapping Null -> Null